# Connect to MySQL database from VBA without having MySQL installed

Tags: mysql, vba, connection-string, dsn

I can connect to a remote MySQL db from an Excel workbook on my machine no problem using the following connection string:

> Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=`server`;Database=`database`;user=`user`;Password=;Option=3;

..but when others try to use the same workbook the connection can't be made ("Data source name not found and no default driver specified").

I have XAMPP installed so have MySQL running and this probably explains why I have the necessary myodbc5.dll (as per [this](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Providers/mysql-connector-odbc-5-1)) to enable the connection.

How can others without MySQL installed on their machines connect to a MySQL db?

Comment: I don't think that they can.  You're referencing the MySQL ODBC driver directly, so it has to actually be installed.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that there would be some generic driver already in Windows, even if it was perhaps slower, that could be used instead.

Comment: in my experience, you have to unfortunately rely on the MySQL drive being installed, which is a real pain.  You could set up a Windows-based server application of sorts that works seamlessly with Windows' current drivers and is responsible for communicating with MySQL, but it sounds like this is more complicated that what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They probably just need the [database driver.](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html)

A quick search for "odbc drivers generic windows" came back with [3rd party generic drivers](http://www.openlinksw.com/info/docs/rel3doc/odbcwin.htm), so there are likely deficiencies with the ones that ship with Windows.

Comment: Is this a requirement for accessing MySQL on a normal Windows install then?  I was rather hoping there was some generic data connection that could be used.

Comment: @Lunatik I believe there are generic connections, but "generic" in Windows isn't usually very generic.